# regex to find pattern "word.word.word = "

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

Inside a .vb file, in Visual Studio 2013, I am trying to find all occurrence of

```
parent.child.property =
```

I am a complete newbie to reg-ex. So far I have been only able to put together

```
\w\s[=]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show or tell us what have you tried and what concrete problem do you have as SO is not "write me some code" portal.

Comment: @JeffBridgman The VS tag may be more appropriate than a language if the search is done through "Find and Replace" within the editor. The VB file may just be the input.

Comment: @KonradKokosa If I knew how to write the regex, will I be posting the question here? unfortunately in my situation, the answer itself will be the code. I have tried reading http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html , but kind of very tough read for a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you listed should match a part of the desired string:

```
    parent.child.property =
//                      ^^^
```

`\w` and `\s` on their own just only match a single character (`y` for `\w` and  for `\s`). Providing a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (such as `+` for "1 or more") after each of them will allow them to repeat to match successive characters (`property` for `\w+`).

```
\w+\s+=
```

```
    parent.child.property =
//               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

To match `parent.child.` before that, you can use a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to match the combination of a "word" followed by a period, adding a quantifier after it (`*` for "zero or more") to repeat the entire group as needed.

```
(?:\w+\.)*\w+\s+=
```

Comment: Thanks so much: a slightly better one will be: (?:\w+\.)+(?:\w+\.)\w+\s+=

Comment: * stands for "zero or more", what do I use if I want "one or more"?

Comment: `+` is "one or more." It's used with `\w` in the snippets I posted.

Comment: I thought '+' was for: "and/plus what follows ahead" or "one more". In other words, for my pattern I used your answer(first part), and I repeated it with a '+' , to indicate, one more like this (and hence I was able to construct, "word."+"word."+"word"+"white space+"="), am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: No, the overall pattern will already handle "followed by" without a special operator. The `+` is a shorthand for `{1,}`, meaning "minimum of 1, maximum unlimited.". Quantifiers like it are similar to loops, repeating what's immediately before them in the pattern. So, `\w+\s+` can be read as "*one or more 'word' characters followed by one or more 'whitespace' characters*." [Visual representation.](http://www.regexper.com/#(%3F%3A%5Cw%2B%5C.)*%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2B%3D)

Comment: Thanks for that website link, it helped me make my re-gex much simpler.  \w+\.+\w+\.+\w+\s+=

Comment: Could you not do it more simply like so `(?:\w+\s*\.?)+=`

Comment: @DomStepek VS2013 just kept spinning when I used your pattern.

Comment: @krprasad my apologies. I had only tried it on Regex101 and I had presumed it would work because it did on there.

Comment: @krprasad Actually I just tried it and it worked fine. Try this and see if it works `MsgBox(Regex.Match("parent.child.property =", "(?:\w+\s*\.?)+=").Value)`